# "Thread.sleep()" has some strange side effects, working with "write()"

Tags: multithreading, d

I'm trying to change the output in Windows console dynamically with this code:

```
for(int i = 0;; i++,Thread.sleep(dur!("msecs")(200)))
    write("\r",i);
```

But you'll have to wait for a long time to see something on screen. Even changed to 1 msec, the duration will be enough to slow down numbers rewriting to 2-3 seconds.

The output changes like this (somewhere about):

```
23343
30948332
42048332
```

It seems like the `write()` function work can be interrupted at the middle of process.

If we change `write()` to `writeln()`, `sleep()` function will work correctly.

Why does it happening so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `stdout.flush()` after every call to `write`. It's because writing is buffered by default, whereas `writeln` (unlike `write`) flushes the output by default.

Answer (score 3):

The output is being buffered.

Insert a call to `stdout.flush()` before the `Thread.sleep` calls to see the output immediately.